# How to replace special characters using regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

Using Asp.net for regex.

I've written an extension method that I want to use to replace whole words - a word might also be a single special character like '&'.

In this case I want to replace '&' with 'and', and I'll need to use the same technique to reverse it back from 'and' to '&', so it must work for whole words only and not extended words like 'hand'.

I've tried a few variations for the regex pattern - started with '\bWORD\b' which didn't work at all for the ampersand, and now have '\sWORD\s' which almost works except that it also removes the spaces around the word, meaning that a phrase like "health & beauty" ends up as "healthandbeauty".

Any help appreciated.

Here's the extension method:

```
    public static string ReplaceWord(this string @this,
        string wordToFind,
        string replacement,
        RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.None)
    {
        Guard.String.NotEmpty(() => @this);
        Guard.String.NotEmpty(() => wordToFind);
        Guard.String.NotEmpty(() => replacement);

        var pattern = string.Format(@"\s{0}\s", wordToFind);

        return Regex.Replace(@this, pattern, replacement, regexOptions);
    }
```

Comment: Try `var pattern = string.Format(@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", wordToFind);`

Comment: Works! Cheers Wiktor, you're a star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match a dynamic string that should be enclosed with spaces (or be located at the start or end of string), you can use *negative lookaheads*:

```
var pattern = string.Format(@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", wordToFind);
                              ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^
```

or even safer:

```
var pattern = string.Format(@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", Regex.Escape(wordToFind));
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?<!\S)` lookbehind will fail the match if the word is not preceded with a non-whitespace character and `(?!\S)` lookahead will fail the match if the word is not followed with a non-whitespace character.